# How to check if a Singleton is already initialized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I have a Singleton class in `Objective-C`. I want to know if the shared object is already initialized or not, before accessing `sharedInstance`. How can I do so?

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static MyObject *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {}
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The shared object is initialized inside `sharedInstance` method. So before you call this method, the answer will be no. If you want to have a method to check, create another class method to check `sharedInstance`.

Comment: One way would be to add a static boolean, which is initially `NO`.  Set it to `YES` in `sharedInstance`.  You can't check `sharedInstance` for `nil` since any reference to `sharedInstance` will cause it to be initialised.

Comment: You can check the value of `onceToken`, but a class boolean could be used instead too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 possible ways:

**First approach:** Move `static MyObject *sharedInstance = nil;` outside of the method. It will look like:

```
@implementation MyObject

static MyObject *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (BOOL)isSharedInstanceInitialized {
    return sharedInatance != nil; 
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {}
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Second approach:** As suggested in the comments above to use additional `BOOL` static value

```
@implementation MyObject

static BOOL isInitialized = NO;

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static MyObject *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        isInitialized = YES;
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (BOOL)isSharedInstanceInitialized {
    return isInitialized;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {}
    return self;
}

@end
```